# Divide column by the previous column[SOLVED]

Tags: r

I'm trying to divide each column in a dataset by the previous column in the dataset for each row, but not by hard coding the values. For example, if I had the table:

```
DATE         0         1       2
07/01/2022   5         4       3
08/01/2022   4         3       2
09/01/2022   2         2       1
```

I would want to divide rows labeled 0 through 2 by the preceding number(NA for the first one).

I tried lag, but that works in columns and not rows.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry, fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transposing will cause problems if there are more than one row. An alternative base R option without transposing (using a slightly expanded dataset to demonstrate that its vectorized across rows):

```
df[-1] / df[-ncol(df)]
```

Or if you want the first column `NA`:

```
cbind(A = NA, df[-1] / df[-ncol(df)])
```

Output:

```
   A         B         C         D         E
1 NA 0.8000000 0.7500000 0.6666667 0.5000000
2 NA 0.8333333 0.8000000 0.7500000 0.6666667
3 NA 0.8571429 0.8333333 0.8000000 0.7500000
```

Or with specific columns (per comment). Here, columns 2 through 4 only:

```
cols <- 2:4
df[cols] / df[cols - 1]

#          B         C         D
#1 0.8000000 0.7500000 0.6666667
#2 0.8333333 0.8000000 0.7500000
#3 0.8571429 0.8333333 0.8000000
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(A = 5:7, B = 4:6, C = 3:5, D = 2:4, E = 1:3)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do this with specific columns? For example, columns 0:12? –

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the following error: Error in .[df, cols] : incorrect number of dimensions.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant help you further unless you edit your question to provide example data more closely aligned with your real data

Comment: Attached a sample table

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
tdf <- t(df)
res <- tdf / c(NA, tdf[-length(tdf)])
res
```

Input Data:

```
df <- data.frame(x0 = 5, x1 = 4, x2 = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do this with specific columns? For example, columns 0:12?